# using appDelegate to share data - getting "request for member in __ not in structure or union"

Tags: objective-c

I've got a simple example where i have a delegate that has a string, along with a property to expose it.

myAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *rootController;
    NSString* myText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myText;
@end
```

myAppDelegate.m

```
#import "myAppDelegate.h"
@implementation myAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize rootController;
@synthesize myText;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [rootController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

So in my main view controller, I try something like this:

```
myAppDelegate* ad = (myAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
ad.myText = @"blah";
```

and I get: Request for member 'myText' in something not a structure or union

does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using setter instead of dot notation?

```
[ad setMyText:@"blah"];
```